# function to add two dynamic arrays together, could this work?

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

So my goal is to have a function that allows to add two dynamically allocated Arrays together. Would the Code I provided work? And is it a good way or are there better ways?

**Code:**

```
template <class T>
T add_arrays(T BASE,int size_BASE, T ADD, int size_ADD, bool delInput) {
    T new_Alloc = new T[size_BASE + size_ADD];

    for (int i = 0; i < size_BASE; i++) {
        new_Alloc[i] = BASE[i];
    }

    for (int i = size_BASE; i < size_ADD; i++) {
        new_Alloc[i] = ADD[i];
    }

    if (delInput) {
        delete[] BASE;
        delete[] ADD;
    }
    return new_Alloc;
}
```

**EDIT:** According to the Answers, the following above shown Code works.
If needed you can feel free to Copy it

Comment: Beware that all identifiers that begin with an underscore and that are followed by a capital letter are reserved. You must not use them. Identifiers like `_BASE`, and `_ADD` are not allowed. [Reserved identifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers#:~:text=the%20identifiers%20with%20a%20double,reserved%20in%20the%20global%20namespace.)

Comment: *Would the Code I provided work?* Do you have any reason to think it doesn't? And sure, the code could be improved, but that's a bit off-topic.

Comment: With `std::vector` this is a one-liner: `std::copy(source.begin(), source.end(), std::back_inserter(dest));` and you let `dest` be destroyed.

Comment: No, the code provided does not compile as written, once called.  Please provide a [mcve].  Posting pseudo code is nearly useless.  Try before you ask so you can fix the trivial syntax errors.  Heck don't even call it : `dynAlloc_pushFuse<int*>` itself fails to compile.

Comment: @cdhowie You also need to `reserve` on `dest` with the right size to be equivalent. `dest.insert(std::end(dest), std::begin(source), std::end(source));` is the one liner.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I'm not going for strict equivalence (though that would be a good optimization). I'm going for "not a maintenance nightmare."

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Im sorry, but could you atleast tell me what is not working about this?

Comment: Copy paste your own code into your own compiler.  Instantiate the template like this: `(void)add_arrays<int>`.  Notice your code doesn't compile.  So no, that could not work.  This is really, really basic stuff you should do before asking someone else to look at your code.